# My while loop from database is repeating results. I know it's my poorly formatted query.

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a query to bring results from my database. It works... until there are more than 2 results that it, then it just repeats some results before adding in new ones.

I know it will be because my query is fairly poor, can anyone advise me?

The idea is

1. connect to database with photo links
2. get the default user picture as $profile_main
3. join the words "photo_" with the default picture number and call it
   $answer (ex: column 'photo_1' in database)
4. now check the database again and get the results for $answer and
   output all information from that database column.

```php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_photos");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $profile_main = $row['default'];
    $answer = "photo_" . $profile_main;

        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT $answer FROM tbl_photos");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))

        {
            echo "<img src=\"" . $row[0] . "\">";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your tbl_photos structure.

Comment: I know the problem is because I have a whileloop within a whileloop, but I dont know how else I can do it. I use the first loop to get some information, then need that information to query the database again for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_fetch_row returns numerical indexes instead of column names (so ['default'] just won't work)...

This is how I would do it if I'm understanding you correctly:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_photos");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $answer = $row['photo_'.$row['default']];
    echo "<img src=\"" . $answer . "\">";
    }
```

Anyway, this is assuming default and photo_x are in the same row.

Comment: It took an hour, but you got it. SOLVED BY YOUUUU
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one result for a photo then you can use `LIMIT` like this

`SELECT $answer FROM tbl_photos LIMIT 1`

Comment: No, that actually turns the problem on its head and now instead of repeating some results, it completely misses them out

Comment: view source ctrl+U and check if `img` code are generated if yes then may be first image does not exists, check path

Answer (score 0):

First, both loops you set same $row variable. Use 2 different variable names so that the results don't get mixed up.

Second issue is that you have you have 2 loops , so it will show all results each time. You need to break in the second loop. Like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_photos");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $profile_main = $row['default'];
    $answer = "photo_" . $profile_main;

        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT $answer FROM tbl_photos");
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))

        {
            echo "<img src=\"" . $row2[0] . "\">";
            break;
        }
}
```

Or by using only one query, it would be much more efficient:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_photos");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $profile_main = $row['default'];
    $answer = "photo_" . $profile_main;        
    echo "<img src=\"" . $row[$answer] . "\">";

}
```

Comment: It just outputs the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You only require 1 query.

TRY

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_photos");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $photo = "photo_" .($row['default'];
    echo "<img src=\"" . $photo . "\">";
    }
```

Comment: I expect you are most likely right, but I get an error because it wants the bit being joined to be between quotes... this bit

Comment: That updated code just outputs the column that contains the main user photo.

Comment: I need to then query that column and output the result... then it should work :) Ideas? - My head is fried, i've been coding all week